# android studio - I can't load My SDK packages

Tags: android, installation

Helloo Hope you answer me To this Question that Really really confused about   , I 've installed My android studio (I don't Have A connection on my computer ) , Then The Programme Asked Me To Put A proxy and I did'nt ....... Now When I've wanted to install API's Fom SDK packages , My SDK Manager Would Download Just ANDROID 6 (API 23) then He Have SHown Me an Error  ==> unable to fech , unknow Host dl.google *** (Something like that )

Comment: please post full error message. we cannot make out what is going wrong with "something like that"

Comment: tell my how you would like to start Android Development if your IDE cannot download necessary libs because of you don't have a connection

Comment: on Google's Android Dev site there's also Android Studio .zip available as I remeber it has already API 23

Answer (score 0):

It shows you " unable to fech , unknow Host dl.google *** " because you do not have an active internet connection on your computer. The SDK manager needs the internet connection to download the selected files from the internet. It is not on your computer already and waiting to be installed by you. And also, you have to note that the API 23 you saw installed, came along with the Android studio IDE you downloaded (as the newest SDK available now). And it asked you to enter a proxy to use just incase you weren't on a direct connection.

**Solution:** Connect your computer to the internet and try again..

Hope this Helps..

Comment: I Appreciate what You've Said ... bu I can't Acces to internet Because I 've A problem ... May I fix This Problem in offline Mode ... Thanks Again

Comment: No, you cannot install the packages in offline mode, but You should be able to use the IDE with only API 23 installed.There's still alot of packages which can be useful, but since you cannot access the internet now, you can do that later.